# stacked barplot from arrays of different lengths

Tags: python, numpy, loops, matplotlib

I am working on an energy balance and I am currently creating a barplot. I want to compare the generation and consumption of electricity over the years. Therefore I have 2 stacked bars for each year. This is how far I got:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

generation_2020 = [20, 30, 40, 20, 10]
consumption_2020 = [50,50]
import_2020 = 20


if import_2020 >0:
    generation_2020 = np.append(generation_2020, import_2020)
else:
    consumption_2020 = np.insert(consumption_2020, 0, import_2020*-1, axis=0)



generation_2025 = np.array([20, 20, 20, 20, 10])
consumption_2025 = np.array([50,50])
import_2025 = -10

if import_2025 >0:
    generation_2025 = np.append(generation_2025, import_2025)
else:
    consumption_2025 = np.insert(consumption_2025, 0, import_2025*-1, axis=0)

data = np.array([generation_2020, generation_2025])
data2 = np.array([consumption_2020, consumption_2025])
label_data = ['renewables','gas','cole', 'storage', 'nuclear', 'import', 'consumption', 'storage']

x2 = ['2020', '2025']
x3 = ['Erzeugung' , '\n\n\n\n\n\n2020', 'Verbrauch', 'Erzeugung' , '\n\n\n\n\n\n2025', 'Verbrauch']
x_pos = np.arange(len(x2))
width = 0.2
x = list()
for i in x_pos:
    x.extend([i-width, i, i+width])  


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    bottom = np.sum(data[:, 0:i], axis=1)
    ax.bar(x_pos - width, data[:, i], bottom=bottom, width=width, label=f"label {i}")


for i in range(data2.shape[1]):
    bottom = np.sum(data2[:, 0:i], axis=1)
    ax.bar(x_pos+ width, data2[:, i], bottom=bottom, width=width, label=f"label {i}")

ax.set_ylabel('[TWh]')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(x3)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='both',length=0, labelsize = 10)

for label in ax.get_xmajorticklabels():
    if 'u' in label.get_text(): label.set_rotation(90)
ax.margins(y=0.1) # some extra padding to place the bar labels


plt.legend(label_data, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This works if both import_2020 and import_2025 are either both negative or both positive. If one is negative and the other is positive it doesnt.

This is the error message I get:

```
for i in range(data.shape[1]):

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The problem is that generation_2020 and generation_2025 dont have the same length. One has 5 entries and the other 6. Does someone have an Idea how to solve this?

Comment: What does import_2025 do over here?

Comment: It is added to one of the arrays, either generation or consumption, depending  if its positive or negative. And then it is shown in the barplot

Comment: So where one value is negative, one of the list is bound to be longer than the other. In that case, will appending/inserting a dummy value to equalize the length of the list logically make sense in you question? What does generation_2020 represent?

Comment: Hm, I could try that. It represents the electricity generation in the year 2020, divided by the type of energy. The difference between generation and  consumption is the import, thats why sometimes it counts as generation and sometimes as consumption, depending on the balance.

Comment: genius, the plot is actually even better to understand now. I called one import and the other export. Thanks for the Tip!

Comment: That's great! You're welcome.